# I am getting errors but I am unsure how to fix them. I am doing this for a class and this is my first time ever doing this

Tags: html

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Finance Mini Guide</title>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="description" content="The best place on the internet to learn about everything finance.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Stocks, Bonds, Real Estate, Taxes, Financial Literacy">
    <meta name="author" content="Matthew Walker">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Financial Education Mini Guide</h1>
<p>Hello reader.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

These are the errors
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emcSe.png)

I was following the instructions given on my assignment page and even followed the example. When I used the HTML checker to check my work, I got a bunch of errors. The only thing I did differently was used visual studio instead of notepad++ because I could use the live server feature.

Answer (score 0):

I put your code it to the markup validator and it shows up only one error. It's because "title" tags should be inside "head" tags :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Finance Mini Guide</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="The best place on the internet to learn about everything finance.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Stocks, Bonds, Real Estate, Taxes, Financial Literacy">
    <meta name="author" content="Matthew Walker">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Financial Education Mini Guide</h1>
<p>Hello reader.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tested the code and that seems to have done the trick. The example code from the assignment I was given did not put the title in the head tag so I thought it was not a big deal. Thank you for the help.